# Question about multilevel logistic model (mixed intercept logistic model) in Stan code

Tags: r, stan, rstan, rstanarm

I'm trying to write stan code for multilevel logistic regression. The model that I tried is a mixed intercept logistic model with two predictors. The first level is children level and the second level is mom level. When I tried to match the summary result of the code I wrote versus the one generated by function `stan_glmer()`, the results of fixed intercept did not match. First, the data I used as below:

```
library(rstanarm)
library(rstan)

data(guImmun, package = "mlmRev")
summary(guImmun)
require(dplyr)
guImmun <- guImmun %>%
  mutate(immun = ifelse(immun == "N",0,1))
```

Second, the stan code was written as below:

```
data {
    int N; // number of obs 
    int M; // number of groups 
    int K; // number of predictors
    
    int y[N]; // outcome
    row_vector[K] x[N]; // predictors
    int g[N];    // map obs to groups (kids to women)
}
parameters {
    real alpha;
    real a[M]; 
    vector[K] beta;
    real<lower=0,upper=10> sigma;  
}
model {
  alpha ~ normal(0,1);
  a ~ normal(0,sigma);
  beta ~ normal(0,1);
  for(n in 1:N) {
    y[n] ~ bernoulli(inv_logit( alpha + a[g[n]] + x[n]*beta));
  }
}
```

Fitting data to the model:

```
guI_data <- list(g=as.integer(guImmun$mom),
                y=guImmun$immun,
                x=data.frame(guImmun$kid2p, guImmun$mom25p),
                N=nrow(guImmun),
                K=2,
                M=nlevels(guImmun$mom))
ranIntFit <- stan(file = "first_model.stan", data = guI_data,
                  iter = 500, chains = 1)
summary(ranIntFit, pars = c("alpha", "beta", "a[1]", "a[2]", "a[3]", "sigma"),
                          probs = c(0.025, 0.975),
                          digits = 2)
```

I got the following result:
[results of written model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viNhB.png)
However, if I use `stan_glmer()` function, the result would be presented as follows.

```
M1_stanglmer <- stan_glmer(immun ~ kid2p + mom25p + (1 | mom), 
                           family = binomial("logit"), 
                           data = guImmun,
                           iter = 500,
                           chains = 1,
                           seed = 349)
print(M1_stanglmer, digits = 2)
```

But the results do not match, especially the result of fixed intercept.
[Results generated by the stan_glmer() function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9xs5.png)

Could anyone help me figure out what's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, I wouldn't expect an exact equivalence between your model in Stan and the version implemented in stan_glmer, but for models that sample well it's reasonable to expect the estimates to be similar.

However, in your case, there is yet another issue impacting your estimates:

The covariates you are using in the `guI_Data$x` object have values in {1,2}, where the typical implementation would use values in {0,1} to represent a binary covariate. This is what is done in `stan_glmer`.

This coding is apparent if you use `glimpse` to inspect the data structure:

```r
> library(tidyverse)
> glimpse(guI_data)
List of 6
 $ g: int [1:2159] 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 ...
 $ y: num [1:2159] 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ x:'data.frame':  2159 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ guImmun.kid2p : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
  ..$ guImmun.mom25p: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ N: int 2159
 $ K: num 2
 $ M: int 1595
```

This is having the biggest impact in your intercept parameter, since the intercept represents the expected linear predictor *when all covariates are 0*. That value will often change when covariates are transformed or added.

Actually, I would expect that the estimated coefficients from your fit and the stan_glmer model are in fact similar, once you take this transformation into consideration.

For example, consider:

- define: `x_m = x + 1`
- Your model (m): `yhat_m = alpha_m + x_m1*beta_m1 + x_m2*beta_m2`
- Stan_glmer: `yhat = alpha + x_1*beta_1 + x_2*beta_2`

and substitute:

`yhat_m = alpha_m + (x_1 + 1)*beta_m1 + (x_2 + 1)*beta_m1`

`yhat_m = alpha_m + x_1*beta_m1 + beta_m1 + x_2*beta_m2 + beta_m2`

`yhat_m = alpha_m + beta_m1 + beta_m2 + x_1*beta_m1 + x_2*beta_m2`

If we assume that `yhat_m ~= yhat`, `beta_m1 ~= beta_1`, and `beta_m2 ~= beta_2`... Then

`alpha = alpha_m + beta_m1 + beta_m2`

So, I would expect the stan_glmer alpha (`-1.7`) to be close to the hand-coded Stan alpha + both betas (`-3.2 + 1.7 - 0.1`).

Which indeed it is (`-1.6`).

---

If you furthermore update your Stan data to scale these covariates as {0,1} instead of {1,2}:

```r
guI_data2 <- list(g=as.integer(guImmun$mom),
                y=guImmun$immun,
                x=data.frame(guImmun$kid2p == "Y", guImmun$mom25p == "Y"),
                N=nrow(guImmun),
                K=2,
                M=nlevels(guImmun$mom))
ranIntFit2 <- stan(file = "first_model.stan", data = guI_data2,
                  iter = 500, chains = 1)
```

And look at the output:

```r
> summary(ranIntFit2, pars = c('alpha', 'beta'))
$summary
              mean     se_mean        sd       2.5%        25%        50%           75%      97.5%     n_eff      Rhat
alpha   -1.5110714 0.022982199 0.1903571 -1.8974997 -1.6318370 -1.5038593 -1.3861628334 -1.1729671  68.60488 1.0505237
beta[1]  1.5224756 0.025017739 0.1737332  1.2260666  1.4058789  1.5118314  1.6492158203  1.8673450  48.22471 1.0592955
beta[2] -0.1206084 0.009410305 0.1640406 -0.4267987 -0.2368855 -0.1267984 -0.0003187197  0.1894375 303.87510 0.9964177
```

You can confirm for yourself that you are in the right ballpark.

After this, the differences between your model and the `stan_glmer` will come down to the priors, the parameterization of hierarchical parameters, the sampling quality, etc.

Aside: there are a number of ways that [categorical covariates can be coded into a model.matrix](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/faq/coding-systems-for-categorical-variables-in-regression-analysis/), each for a specific interpretation of the effect parameters. The models are usually equivalent, meaning that one can convert from one parameterization to another using linear transformations of effects as done above.